# How to trigger plugin migration code when plugin updates?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, migration

I'm looking to run some migration related code when my plugin is updated to the next release. I've researched and yet to find any sort of hook/trigger which will be called when a plugin has successfully upgraded.

All the suggestions I've found so far suggest to run migration on admin_init() and cross check a stored plugin version in options. But this seems like a really "hacky" solution and would imagine there must be a more structured way to run migrations (database related) when a plugin is updated from a pervious version.

What is the best way to trigger migration code for a plugin when it has been updated both manually and automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plugin update in WordPress is basically removing it and installing again, so there is no special hook for this action.

So this hacky solution is the best one:

- Save in options your last version
- On init, check if current version is newer than saved version
- If yes, perform your SQL actions

Comment: With the "On Init", surely that will require the user to visit the admin/settings page for the plugin otherwise the site could stay broken until they do if migration is breaking changes (ie: changing options names)

Comment: Init is called at the beginning, before options are loaded, or content is printed:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
It is safe to make such changes on init.